# Termwise Integration of Fourier Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

This is a question from Edwards and Penney 4th edition Differential Equations and Boundary value problems from section 9.3.

Suppose that $f(t)$ is a piecewise continuous period $2L$ funtion.

Define $$F(t) =  \int \limits_0^t[f(s) - \frac 12a_0]ds$$. Where ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ denote the Fourier coefficients of f(t)

Show that $F(t + 2L) = F(t). $

I feel like this isn't always true unless we impose conditions on $F(2L)$ and $F(0)$.

Comment: I take it you mean to impose conditions of $f(2l)$ and $f(0)$. You seem to have forgotten something in the definition of $F$.

Comment: When you say $f$ is piecewise continuous, does this entail $f$ being continuous in $]0,2L[$?

Comment: @ Git Gud: You interpret this question as you like. I typed it verbatim from the book. Thanks for correcting my symbols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of $F$:

$$F(t+2L) - F(t) = \int_t^{t+2L} f(s) - \frac{1}{2} a_0\,ds = \int_{t}^{t+2L}f(s)\,ds - a_0 L.$$

By the periodicity of $f$, we have

$$\int_t^{t+2L} f(s)\,ds = \int_0^{2L} f(s)\,ds,$$

and by definition of the Fourier coefficients,

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{L}\int_0^{2L} f(s)\,ds.$$

That means we have indeed

$$F(t+2L) - F(t) = 0$$

for all $t$, i.e. $F$ is $2L$-periodic.